# Can't set imageview background in custom list adapter

Tags: java, android, list, chat

I'm creating an android chat app.. The main screen will be a list of messages.. I get the messages and the friends from the database then show it in my list which contains two textviews and 1 imageview.. every thing works fine, but when i get my friends from database(not the same size of messages) and I need to get Imagepath of each friend.. that works fine also when i log it.. but when I try to get it in the adapter i get my list with only one unit..

```
        messages_iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final String name = items.get(position).getTitle();
        final String photoUrl = friends.get(1).getPhotoUrl();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Button Clicked", "Name: " + name);
                Log.d("Button Clicked", "URL: " + photoUrl);

                getPhoto(messages_iv, photoUrl);
            }
        }).start();
```

when I try friends.get(0) it works fine.. but when I try friends.get(1) I get : 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Any Idea ??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you making sure that your list has a bigger size than 1 ?

Comment: That's because `friends` only have 1 element, therefore there is no element number 2

Comment: Check the size of your `List` before referencing its items by index.

Comment: What is the code for `friends`?

Comment: We are going to need more information. How is your friends variable populated? That error means that you are accessing an index in your list that does not exist.

Comment: My list has 2 elements and when i log it from outside the adapter i get the 2 elements